# Running queries, good design here?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry for posting so many nubbin questions on ASP.net, I'm getting the hang of it slowly.

I execute queries on my pages as such (working):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">

    // When the registration form is submitted
    protected void regSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // No erros so far
        Boolean anyError = false;
        string errorMessages = "";

        // Take all form values
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password1 = txtPassword1.Text;
        string password2 = txtPassword2.Text;
        string emailAdd = txtEmail.Text;

        // Verify that username is unique
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = '" + username + "'", cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            rdr.Read();
            int result = int.Parse(rdr[0].ToString()); //read a value
        }


        statusLabel.Text = username;
    }
</script>
```

My question is, is this the best practise, do I have to have a 'using' block and that inner structure for every query I run, or is there a simpler way of doing it?  Also, do I need to close anything off or does the garbage man take care of it?

In Classic ASP I would just have a

```
adoCon.execute("DELETE FROM TABLE")
```

or a

```
rsCommon.open("SELECT * FROM TABLE"), adoCon
do until rsCommon.EOF

rscommon.movenext
loop
rsCommon.close
```

Tallyho!  Thank you for any help!
Which seems a lot simpler and intuitive to me.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing about intermingling SQL inside your .aspx pages that is "best practice".

Comment: It has to be said, `DELETE FROM TABLE` will delete the entire contents of that table.  Don't do it :)

Comment: From the <% it does seem as though u are putting your code in the aspx file. In ASP.net, the web page (.asp from asp) is now split into aspx + aspx.cs and for separation of HTML markup from C# / VB code, its usually a best practice to put the C# code into the aspx.cs / aspx.vb file

Comment: This is a good question for a beginner.  You're thinking along the right tracks.

Comment: @Kirk, where should the SQL go then?  I've come from a classic ASP background and it is normal to put it within pages.  Stored procedures are the only other places I can think it goes?

Comment: I'd venture to say that most .NET developers use the code-behind model, rather than inline. (http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/aspnet/doc/pages/codebehind.aspx) This is probably due to the fact that Visual Studio (the most common IDE for ASP.NET) uses the code-behind model. However, there is a place for Inline code. (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/code-behind-vs-inline-code.html)

Comment: BTW, are you doing this all in Notepad?  Are you using an IDE?  VS Express is free of charge...  http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tom,

You've got a few bits of bad stuff going on here (sorry to be so blunt). I'd look at the following:

- Parameterize your queries to mitigate
  SQL injection attacks
- Seperate your logic out into DAL and
  BLL layers (or at the very least,
  isolate it for reuse into classes where possible)

Also, `Boolean anyError = false;` never get's used but i'm assuming that's for later use.

On the bright side, the idea of the using block is good, so keep that up. You can find references online to help with decoupling your logic and parameterized queries.

go with the flow

jim

Comment: Man, I completely missed the SQL Injection, as I was focused on the using statement.  Good catch!  +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks, I used a simple example, unused variables are for later use, and I will be using SQL parameters.

Comment: Also, be as blunt as you want, I am here to learn, nothing else!

Comment: tom  - i appreciate that. but yes, definately make it your priority to work on security in tandem with garbage collection concerns. there's an old adage that says 'never prematurely optimize'. what that actually means to me in any app is to look at the foundations 1st before looking at any optimizations. those foundations are in effect your best practice measures such as parameterisation, decoupling etc. good luck with the refactoring as i think it's very useful to hear balanced opinion on key topics such as this.

Comment: Could you expand on DAL and BLL layers a bit more?

Comment: I'll add one more - this should all be done using the asp.net membership system in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for tips on using .net membership system, I'll read up on that.

Comment: Tom, it's a huge topic (BLL/DAL). get two people in a room and you'll get 3 opinons on it ;-). however, there are fantastic articles on the web now that make this a very easy process to understand. my all time favourite (as i see you're on webforms) has to be Marco Bellinaso's 'The BeerHouse' book. this runs over almost every 'best practice' that you can think of, covering BLL/DAL membership, security etc, etc. give it a google. http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0764584642?tag=coderjournal-20

Answer (score 3):

The "using" block is not a MUST have, but it's a good idea.  It takes care of disposing of the object automatically.  (Then you don't have to remember to close it, dispose of it, etc.)

The only change I'd make is I'd change  the line

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString()))
```

to

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString(), CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
```

to ensure the connection gets closed properly.

**Edit - added**

Now that I see the SQL injection flaw, there are other things I would change, but I'm leaving this answer as it's specific to what you were asking.

Since you say you're a newbie, I'd like to STRONGLY recommend you get familiar with the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) and get VERY familiar with it.  There's a lot to learn, but web app security is critical.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` block is a best practice.  However, using string concatenation to build your sql query is just plain **wrong**.   What if someone entered the following into your username field? :

> ';DROP TABLE tblUsers;--

Write it like this instead:

```
// When the registration form is submitted
protected void regSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Verify that username is unique
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString()))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = @UserName", cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUserName.Text;

        cn.Open();
        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
    }

    statusLabel.Text = txtUserName.Text;
}
```

Also, you should really look at using the ASP.Net membership system for all of this rather than building it yourself.  Membership,login, authentication, and other security code is notoriously easy to build *wrong*, such that you have something that you think works and don't discover until a year later you were cracked six months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get into the habit of using `using`, as it decreases the risk you'll forget to close connections and start hitting your server's connection pool limits.

If you're just getting a single value (such as a SELECT COUNT) you can use `ExecuteScalar` to make things a bit more compact. But as Jim says above, make sure you parameterise your queries, otherwise you're leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = @UserName", cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
cn.Open();

int result = Convert.ToInt32(new SqlCommand(sql, cn).ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

The using block is not necesarry but it makes sure that when it reaches the closing bracket the object is properly disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

1. Working directly with a database from your ASPX page (or code-behind) is not a good practice. Most professional projects start from a 3-tier design where the font-end calls a business layer from which the data layer is also abstracted. More on 3-tier design [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture).
2. Your connection will be closed at the end of your using block, which is the easiest way to handle that.